# PHP Assign php variable into another php condition

Tags: php, yii

I know this question might be simple ...

Im currently using yii framework for development. Bellow is my coding:

**In Controller:**

```
    $gamecat      = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->find($app_id);
    $cat         = CHtml::encode($gamecat->gamecat);

    $gametypeid  = 'id=';
    $gametype    = GamesType::model()->find($gametypeid);
```

I tried

```
    $gametypeid  = 'id=.$cat';
```

How can I assign `$cat` to `$gametypeid = 'id=$cat'` ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$gametypeid = 'id=' . $cat;

$gametypeid = "id=$cat";
```

Does this achieve what you want to do?

Comment: yes ! I thought can't assign outside `''` ... thanks !